# mask an image on an angle

Tags: html, css, mask, clip

I am making an accordion that is meant to have slanted elements, I have got the accordion functionality working, but I am struggling to create the slanted effect, I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMhcY/1/)

and also here is my code,

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="set" id="first" data-width="261">
      <div class="accord">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/872/690" />
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set active" id="second" data-width="106">
    <div class="accord">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/872/690" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set" id="third" data-width="113">
    <div class="accord">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/872/690" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set" id="fourth" data-width="71">
    <div class="accord">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/872/690" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set" id="fifth" data-width="24">
    <div class="accord">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/872/690" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set" id="sixth" data-width="89">
    <div class="accord">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/872/690" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  *, html { padding:0; margin:0; }
    #accordion { white-space:nowrap;background:black; width:2000px; height:690px; }
    .set { white-space:normal; display:inline-block; position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
    .active { width:872px; }
    #first { width:261px; }
    #third { width:113px; }
    #fourth { width:71px; }
    #fifth { width:24px; }
    #sixth { width:89px; }

    .set:after {
      width:15px;
      height:15px;
      display:block;
      background:red;
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      right:0px;
      content:"";
    }

    .set:before { 
       width:1px;
       background:red;
       display:block;
       position:absolute;
       height:100%;
       -webkit-transform:rotate(9deg);
       content: " ";
       top:0px;
       right:68px;
    }
```

```
$("#accordion .set").click(function() {
  var active = $(this).parent().find(".active");
  active.animate({"width" : active.data('width')}, 1000);
  active.removeClass("active");
  $(this).animate({"width" : 872}, 1000);
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

What I am trying to do is mask out every that is after the red slanted line, I have so far tried, 'clip'

Answer (score 3):

Skew the parent of the image, and then unskew (skew by the opposite angle) the image. Something like

```
.set { transform: skewX(-10deg); }
.set img { transform: skewX(10deg); }
```

***Notes***:

- Make sure the image has `display: block` (or `inline-block`) or else
  the transform won't work.
- [`transform` needs `-webkit-` prefix for WebKit browsers and `-ms-`
  prefix for IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)
- I think you could simplify your markup - I'm not sure why you need the `.accord` wrapper around the images.